# Azure Ad Error The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client's application registration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am using azure ad app (multi-tenant) to get interactive access token and then send email in .net desktop app. I have client id, tenant (organizations), redirect url ( "http://localhost" ). Works as expected on my machine. I gave this demo app to my teammate to get access token using his email (same organization, same client id, same redirect url). The interactive window is shown but when he logs in, this error is displayed:

AADSTS650057: Invalid resource. The client has requested access to a resource which is not listed in the requested permissions in the client's application registration. Client app ID: ---clientId---(App2). Resource value from request: https://outlook.office365.com. Resource app ID: 00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000. List of valid resources from app registration: 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000.
Trace ID: deada8ff-60ac-4051-877a-093aa1af8f00
Correlation ID: ddc9c0b7-d6dd-40dd-8331-6f592db6a401
Timestamp: 2023-10-18 17:51:45Z

Api Permissions:
[image]

Demo code

```
                pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                    .Create(ClientId)
                    .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, Tenant)
                    .WithRedirectUri(RedirectUrl)
                    .Build();

 var outlookScope = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };

if (accountsResult.Any())
            {
                try
                {
                    var acquireSilentTask = Task.Run(() => pca
                        .AcquireTokenSilent(outlookScope, accountsResult.FirstOrDefault())
                        .ExecuteAsync());

                    //
                    // Blocking call to acquire token silently
                    //
                    result = acquireSilentTask.Result;
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    var acquireInteractiveTask = Task.Run(() => pca
                        .AcquireTokenInteractive(outlookScope)
                        .ExecuteAsync());

                    //
                    // Blocking call to acquire token interactively
                    //
                    result = acquireInteractiveTask.Result;
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Could you confirm whether that user is from same tenant as you or not? Please include what scope you are requesting with what API permissions in App2.

Comment: Yes the user is on the same tenant as me. Please see the updated question, i have added api permissions and .dot net code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I registered one multi-tenant application and added same **API permissions** as below:

[image]

When I ran similar code with https://outlook.office365.com/.default as **scope**, interactive window opened to sign in with *Pick an account* screen as below:

[image]

After logging in with above test account, I too got **same error** as you like below:

[image]

> The error occurred as you added *Microsoft Graph* permissions but requesting token for ***Office 365 Exchange Online*** without adding those permission in app registration.

To resolve the error, you need to either add ***Office 365 Exchange Online*** permissions in your App Registration or modify your scope by including that specific permission instead of `/.default`.

In my case, I added Office 365 Exchange Online API permissions of **Delegated** type as below:

[image]

When I ran the same code with https://outlook.office365.com/.default as **scope**, I got **consent screen** after logging in as below:

[image]

After accepting the above consent, I got **access token** in output console successfully as below:

[image]

When I decoded the above token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms), I got **`aud`** and **`scp`** claims with valid values:

[image]

Alternatively, you can also change your scope from https://outlook.office365.com/.default to **specific permission** in your code like this:

```cs
var outlookScope = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/Mail.Send" };
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Sridevi. One question, will " https://outlook.office365.com/SMTP.Send" work ? And also how can i add Office 365 Exchange Online Mail.Send in Api permissions

Comment: Yes https://outlook.office365.com/SMTP.Send will also work. To add Office 365 Exchange Online `Mail.Send` permission, go to _API permissions -> Add a permission -> APIs my organization uses -> Search  Office 365 Exchange Online -> Select permissions -> Add_ like [this](https://i.imgur.com/uOIdhKP.png)